# Launch OneNote using Share Intent in Android

Tags: android, onenote

Apparently Microsoft has added some Share Intent support to the OneNote Android app: http://www.xda-developers.com/massive-facelift-to-microsoft-onenote-for-android-brings-share-intent-and-multi-window-support/

How can I use a Share Intent on Android to launch the OneNote app?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you'll just want to fire off an intent with a 'share' action (OneNote supports both `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`, with any mime type). If a user has the OneNote app installed, it'll show up in the list of options to share with. Hypothetically speaking you could limit the share action to the OneNote app (i.e. by setting the target package name on the intent), if that's what you're asking, but generally this is considered bad practice, especially as there's no guarantee the target app will be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly launch OneNote through the Share Intent. The behaviour that occurs is:

1. Content is sent to the OneNote app
2. Page is created with title matching `EXTRA_SUBJECT` and body as sent in `EXTRA_TEXT`.
3. Low priority notification indicating a page has been created fires. Target is set to open OneNote to the View Page activity.

I suppose that if you asked for the Notifications permission you could intercept the Notification and open OneNote yourself at that point.

If you simply want to open OneNote, why not just use something like:

```
String onPackageName = "com.microsoft.office.onenote";
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
                      getLaunchIntentForPackage(onPackageName);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```