# How to send URL to OneNote Android App?

Tags: android, android-intent, onenote

I have a URL that I want the user to open in OneNote or a web browser using an Android intent. With web browser it's easy. I just use `ACTION_SEND` and set the intent data with the url.

How do I add OneNote app (if available) to the list of apps to choose from as well as send this URL data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following code:

```
String url = link.Uri;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this other question, it should have all your answers

[Launch OneNote using Share Intent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635269/launch-onenote-using-share-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Edit

```
String onPackageName = "com.microsoft.office.onenote";
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
                        getLaunchIntentForPackage(onPackageName);
                launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                launchIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,"Hello world");
                launchIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hello world");
                launchIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"htttp://www.google.com");
                startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: It seems you can't share directly to OneNote, and your code it's just a simple sharing intent which prompts the usual "Share to" windows

Comment: @RajeshNasit I was sleeping :) It doesn't quite work. The URL I want to send to onenote is a onenote notebook itself, so I was hoping it would actually open the notebook in onenote. The code you provided pastes the link into a new page.

Comment: can you give me that sample url?